# why can I not include 2 variables in the first statement of a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting the error: array must be initialised with a brace-enclosed initialiser

This is the code:

```
for (int i=1, seporated_words[0]=sentence[0]; sentence[i]!=' '; i++)
{
seporated_words[0]=seporated_words[0]+sentence[i];
}
cout << seporated_words[0];
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such are the syntax rules of C++. `int i = 1, seporated_words[0]...` tries to define two variables - an integer `i` and an array `seporated_words`, with size of the array 0. Following `= ...` is seen by a compiler as initialization of the said array, and an incorrect one (still wouldn't be correct to have a zero-sized array, but compiler is not there to report it yet).

You should either set `seporated_words` to desired value before the loop statement - it seems to be external to the loop anyways, or make `i` an external variable, and initialize it in the loop initialazer together with `seporated_words`.

Btw, you have a typo - it is spelled `separated`.

Comment: Oh ok so is what your saying that anything you include in the first section of the for loop the compiler assumes is a declaration?

Comment: @AmeenIzhac not everything. But you made it a declaration by supplying type `int i = 0` is a declaration, `i = 0` is an assignment.

Comment: but I thought the comment separated the declaration to the assignment

Comment: @AmeenIzhac - comma does not separate the rest of the statement from the declaration. Outside of a loop, the statement `int a = 1, b = 2` makes the statement a declaration for both `a` and `b`. This applies inside the loop as well. You can't have `int a=0, char b=0` outside a loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

you have two closed braces!

The first part of `for` loop runs only once. You can place `seporated_words[0]=sentence[0]` before `for`.